# Angular: $scope.msg Appearing in Console, Not on DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've ran into a bit of a problem, wherein I've created a `$scope.msg` and it's printing to my console just fine, but it won't render itself on the DOM. I'm using Browserify to require angular and bundle my js.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="zeroApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var angular = require('angular');
  angular.module('zeroApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.msg = "Hello Angular!";
      console.log($scope.msg);
  }]);
})();
```

Any reason why this isn't being exposed to the DOM and my `<h1>` element is empty?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should work..any console error?

Comment: Zero console error. The console just returns the log: "Hello Angular!"

Comment: Seems to work [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29Luq8ns/). Am I missing anything here? Note I removed `var angular = require('angular');` in the fiddle for conciseness

Comment: If it's worth posting, heres my `app.js` file outputted by Browserify: https://gist.github.com/realph/b97d1fc27b498bb3794f#file-app-js

Comment: What happens if you inspect the DOM element ? Maybe you have a CSS that hides it ? You can also do a controller call that writes to console instead of `{{msg}}` to see if it reaches it.

Comment: I have zero CSS. I'm writing to the console by doing `console.log($scope.msg);`, how do I do a controller call?

Comment: do a `{{ test() }}` instead of the `{{ msg }}` and have a `$scope.test = function () { console.log('call works'); };` in your controller, see if that gets it.

Comment: @OmriAharon Nothing appearing in the console. I assume that means my controller isn't getting it?

Comment: @realph You assume correctly. Very weird, this should be working according to the code you're showing. There must be something else doing the obstruction.

Comment: @OmriAharon I've uploaded the app here: http://bench.realph.co.uk/angular/ if that's of any help.

Comment: @realph If I'm supposed to be a red screen with "Hello World!" in the middle then it's working for me.

Comment: Silly me. I've figured out the issue. Was using Swig in my `gulpfile.js` to do HTML templating. The mustache templating must have been conflicting with Angular's templating lang. Took it out of my build process and it works like a charm. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not an Angular expert so I can't explain the details, but the problem is that Angular wont detect that change, and thus it wont be propagated into the view. There are other ways around it, but one rather simple fix is to wrap the message into an extra object. Instead of using `$scope.msg`, try using `$scope.msg.txt` and it should work.

Hopefully someone with more knowledge of Angular's inner workings can clarify this further.

Here's another Fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/29Luq8ns/1/

Notice I'm using `$timeout` in it. That's another way you could work around the problem. By changing `$scope.msg` inside a `$timeout` function, it will work, even without a delay parameter.

Comment: Why won't Angular detect the change? Did you check out the jsfiddle link?

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest I did, but the thing is that in that Fiddle the variable is initialized at load, and not later on in the code, so it isn't really changing as such. As for the reason why Angular wont detect changes in the first children of `$scope`, I really don't know. It's always puzzled me, and I've just worked around it.

Comment: I've tried `$scope.msg = { txt: "Hello Angular!" };` and `<h1>{{ msg.txt }}</h1>` with no luck. So weird.

Comment: @realph That's odd indeed. Are you sure it's the right scope? Try using the `$timeout` method.

Comment: Even if I use the `$timeout` method, still nothing. Really weird. This is what my final app.js file looks like if it's worth looking at: https://gist.github.com/realph/b97d1fc27b498bb3794f#file-app-js

Comment: I really have no idea. :/ The only other thing I can think of is that Angular is not getting initialized, but I don't know anything about Browserify.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using Swig in my gulpfile.js to do render my HTML templates. The mustache templating language of Swig must have been conflicting with Angular's templating lang. Took it out of my build process and it works like a charm.

Thanks for all the help.